# Eloquent: Mutators automated

Tags: laravel

I have a requirement to call some model functions automatically such that whenever I return the model object the value shall exist in the function.

Ex. I have an Invoice model, there is a calculation to be performed for open balance. Now, the calculation off course need some logic and in order to perform that I have create a function

getOpenBalanceAttribute()

While returning an invoice to API response, I need to have the open balance set in it.

Comment: Post a code example or something. Not real clear what it is you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `$appends` Model attribute. The `$appends` attribute allows you to specify accessors to include when the model is converted to an array or json.

Add this to your `Invoice` model:

```
protected $appends = ['open_balance'];
```

You can read more about this, including more advanced or granular usage, in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json).

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you asking but if I'm correct in my assumption you want to set a variable with your own logic based on input value.

Mutators are exactly for these scenarios!

> [Eloquent Mutators:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#introduction) Accessors and mutators allow you to format Eloquent attribute values when you retrieve or set them on model instances.

for example if you have a first_name variable in your model you should define a setter like this:

```
/**
 * Set the user's first name.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return void
 */
public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['first_name'] = strtolower($value);
}
```

in your case the mutator will look like this:

```
public function setOpenBalanceAttribute($value)
{
    $calculatedValue = YourLogicForCalculating($value);
    $this->attributes['open_balance'] = $calculatedValue;
}
```